# Updating Postgres from 9.1.4

Tags: macos, postgresql

I tried to run homebrew install of Postgres and it looks like it's installing 9.1.4 the same as whats con my new Mac 10.8 system. After I ran the command brew install postgresql
and ran initdb /usr/local/var/postgres -E utf8

I checked version .

```
psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 9.1.4

which psql
/usr/local/bin/psql
```

This looks to me like its install the same version which would be originally in /usr/bin/

I'm trying to get it to run the latest version which looks like its 9.2.2
What am I missing here.

Comment: The latest version is actually 9.2.3

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using the [OSX installer](http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgdownload#osx)?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check in `/Library/PostgreSQL/` and see if this directory exists.  From my understanding, Homebrew will often install PostgreSQL into that path.  If this is the case you may have a newer version of PostgreSQL than what you think and setting your `PATH` envar will fix the problem.

If this is the case you will want to set your system to start up only one of the databases, or if it starts up both set them on different ports.